# Matching one value in one column with more than one values in other column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have three tables

```
Student     Student_Interest     Interest
=======     ================     ========
Id          Student_Id           Id
Name        Interest_Id          Name
```

Where Student_Interest.Student_Id refers to Student.Id
and Student_Interest.Interest_Id refers to Interest.Id

Let's say we have three kinds of interest viz. "Java", "C", "C++" and "C#" and there are some entries in the student table and their respective interest mapping entries in the Student_Interest table. (A typical many-to-many relationship)

How can we get the list of students that have both "Java" and "C" as their interests?

Comment: Do a `JOIN` with all the tables.

Comment: But how would you match if both of the interests are present?

i.e. Both interest_id present for that one student_id in student_interest table

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Your future questions would be more convergent by using this feature: [SQL Fiddle](http://goo.gl/50NtF) Good Luck! :)

Comment: Didn't know about this. It's an awesome tool and giving a pre-built schema would surely have narrowed down my question to some very specific answers. Will keep in mind from the next time. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can we get the list of students that have both "Java" and "C" as
>   their interests?

We can write t(t.c,...) to say that row (t.c,...) is in table t. Let's alias Student to s, Student_Interest to sij and sic and Interest to ij and ic. We want rows (s.Id,s.Name) where

```
    s(s.Id,s.Name)
AND sij(sij.Student_Id,sij.Interest_Id) AND s.Id = sij.Student_Id
AND sic(sic.Student_Id,sic.Interest_Id) AND s.Id = sic.Student_Id
AND ij(ij.Id,ij.Name) AND ij.Id=sij.Interest_Id AND ij.Name = 'Java'
AND ic(ic.Id,ic.Name) AND ic.Id=sic.Interest_Id AND ic.Name = 'C'
```

So:

```
select s.Id,s.Name
from Student s
join Student_Interest sij on s.Id = sij.Student_Id
join Student_Interest sic on s.Id = sic.Student_Id
join Interest ij on ij.Id=sij.Interest_Id AND ij.Name = 'Java'
join Interest ic on ic.Id=sic.Interest_Id AND ic.Name = 'C'
```

Comment: Just wondering... is the intro helpful and/or understandable?

Comment: I rather understood more from the query that you wrote. I actually was confused on how to use joins when matching more than one value in a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the Java and C records from student_interest, group by student and see if you get the complete number of interests for a student. With such students found you can display data from the student table.

```
select *
from student
where id in
(
  select student_id
  from student_interest
  where interest_id in (select id from interest where name in ('Java', 'C'))
  group by student_id
  having count(distinct interest_id) = 2
);
```

EDIT: You've asked me to show a query with EXISTS. The straight-forward way would be:

```
select *
from student
where exists
(
  select * 
  from student_interest
  where student_id = student.id
  and interest_id = (select id from interest where name = 'Java')
)
and exists
(
  select * 
  from student_interest
  where student_id = student.id
  and interest_id = (select id from interest where name = 'C')
);
```

For every interest an additional EXISTS clause. If, however, you want to convert the IN query above to an EXISTS query, so to have only one EXISTS clause, you get:

```
select *
from student
where exists
(
  select student_id
  from student_interest
  where student_id = student.id
  and interest_id in (select id from interest where name in ('Java', 'C'))
  group by student_id
  having count(distinct interest_id) = 2
);
```

I find the IN clause more readable, but that's a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: What advantage does this offer over a simple join?

Comment: @Strawberry: Readability. This is especially good for beginners who tend to join everything together and suddenly get confused somewhere which results in too high sums and the like. It is good practise to think of what you actually want to show (records from table student here, not students and their interests).

Comment: I respect your view, but I disagree 100 per cent. I don't think newbies should go anywhere near subqueries until they've understood the basic concept of joins. I'm at such an advantage because I started using SQL (just) before suqueries came along.

Comment: @Strawberry: 100% is a lot. I can just say that I saw more errors on joined queries than on queries with subqueries. Supposedly because the writer didn't put too much thinking into it when joining (whereas the subquery style kind of forces you to think the steps through). However I havent used SQL *that* long. (About twenty years only so far.)

Comment: Well I've only used MySQL, and it's only been around since '95, which puts you at a distinct advantage!

Comment: @Strawberry: Yep, MySQL was a latecomer ;-)

Comment: This does work but I find it more of a tweak when I have to check for count = 2. I rather prefer doing the same thing with joins as @philipxy rightly suggested. Still kudos to the answer.

Comment: Funny. I consider multiple joins a tweak here. When querying the same table more than once to check if the interests in question exist for the user, then EXISTS would be the typical way to go. (Well, just as the name suggests.) Only, think of how the query will look like when you look for four, eight or more interests. And then think of how mine will look like (or Volodymyr's for that matter).

Comment: @ChintanPathak & ThorstenKettner For the given question my solution has fewer & simpler arrangements of fewer & simpler concepts. I agree that generalizing to a list of interest names would use a different structure. But then I would use NOT EXISTS NOT (ie forall) and IN. The choice depends on one's view of the tradeoffs of generally more but simpler arrangements of fewer and simpler concepts (JOIN/IN/EXISTS/NOT) vs fewer but less-simple arrangements of more but less-simple concepts (JOIN/IN/GROUPBY/HAVING/COUNT).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you have a perfectly valid point. I tried applying the (JOIN/IN/EXISTS/NOT) concepts but wasn't able to achieve the desired results. No wonder using them would have made the problem much simpler, if it was possible to do the same using them.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Just wondering, can you formulate the same problem using EXISTS to check for both the values, say for instance "Java" and "C". I tried but didn't work pretty well. Would appreciate if you can figure out a way to do that.

Comment: Sure. I've added EXISTS queries to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I already see a couple of correct answers, but anyway, here is my one:

```
select s.* from student s   
join (
    select si.student_id from student_interest si join interest i on i.id = si.interest_id
    where i.name in ('Java','C') group by si.student_id having count(*) = 2   
) iv on iv.student_id = s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to join all the three tables to get the information as below:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Student s, Student_Interest si, Interest i, Interest sin
WHERE s.Id = si.Student_Id
AND   i.Id = si.Interest_Id
AND   sin.Id = si.Interest_Id
AND   i.Name = 'Java'
AND   sin.Name =  'C'
```

Comment: This would give me the students who have "Java" or "C" as their interest and not both. I tried this.

Comment: join again interest and use i.Name = 'Java' and sin.Name = 'C'. See updated query.

Comment: Here the first condition i.name = "java" would remove the entries in sin where sin.name = "C" and thus would give me zero entries in the final output.

Comment: I don't think we should be encouraging archaic, implicit join syntax in the bright, modern world of SO.

Comment: @Strawberry i understand implicit join is discouraged. But do you know why?

Comment: Well, I can tell you why I discourage it. Principally for two reasons. 1, that it's harder to read (which also means mistakes are more likely), and 2, that it's harder to rewrite as an OUTER JOIN

Comment: @almas shaikh: Because they are less readable and more prone to errors. Example: `select * from a, b where a.c = 1` is a cartesian join. Whether by mistake or voluntarily nobody can say. Whereas `select * from a cross join b where a.c = 1` is a desired cross join obviously and `select * from a inner join b where a.c = 1` is invalid (and the dbms should raise an exception, which MySQL unfortunately doesn't).

Comment: The query doesn't work. One student_interest record can not have an interest_id for Java and for C at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `JOIN` with all the tables. You need to `GROUP BY` the column `Name` to get both interest like below. See a demo fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e80391/13

```
select s.Name
from student s
join Student_Interest si on s.id = si.Student_Id
join Interest i on si.Interest_Id = i.id
join Interest ii on si.Interest_Id = ii.id
group by s.Name
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: This would give me the students who have "Java" or "C" as their interest and not both. I tried this.

Comment: Here the first condition i.name = "java" would remove the entries in ii where ii.name = "C" and thus would give me zero entries in the final output.

Comment: I did. If I just put i.name = "java" then all the entries that I get are of only "java", even in the ii columns. So further keeping ii.name = "C" would make the result set empty.

Comment: Yeah, didn't recognize that. you need to `group by` student name. Try now.

Comment: this would never check for "Java" and "C". It would just give me all entries that have count > 1. Anyways I did get a couple of correct answers. Thanks for the help :)